# Как правильно сказать "жизненные советы"

Tags: значение-слов

Слово *жизненные* в словосочетании *жизненные советы* употреблено неверно. На что его можно заменить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Жизненные советы" употреблено действительно  неверно, советы **ЖИТЕЙСКИЕ,** т.е. бытовые, в житейских ситуациях(отношения в семье, советы по дому), а жизненные -ситуации, образы, т.е. важные для жизни.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что о неправильности употребления нельзя судить без контекста. 
Если это советы как "по жизни" поступать в той или иной ситуации, для жизнедеятельности не критичной, как определяет Людмила - "бытовые", то какую-то неточность можно усмотреть, но и то очень слабую.

Ну а если тут действительно ОБЖ? Как первую помощь оказать, как от нападения уйти? Тогда именно что жизненные, в 3-м значении.

> ЖИЗНЕННЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -знен, -зненна, -зненно. 1. к Жизнь (2 зн.). Ж-ые отправления. Ж. опыт. Ж. путь. 2. Близкий к действительности, типичный для неё. Ж. образ. Речь актрисы лишена штампов и необычайно жизненна. Тема этой картины весьма жизненна. 3. Важный для жизни, общественно необходимый. Ж-ые интересы. Ж. вопрос. Ж-ые центры страны. Ж-ое пространство. <Жизненно, нареч. Ж. важный вопрос. Принять ж. важное решение. Дорога здесь ж. необходима.
>   (БТС, Кузнецов)

Насчет "житейский". Если судить по Кузнецову (при всем скептическом к нему отношении, словарь толковый), то "житейский" - почти точный синоним к одному из значений "жизненный". Не вижу причин обязывать менять шило на мыло.

> ЖИТЕЙСКИЙ, -ая, -ое. Связанный с жизнью, с действительностью; жизненный. Ж. опыт, расчёт. Ж-ая мудрость. Ж-ие наблюдения. // Обыденный, будничный, свойственный повседневной жизни. Ж-ие хлопоты, мелочи, будни. Ж. разговор. ◊ Дело житейское. Оценка каких-л. жизненных обстоятельств как обыкновенных, обыденных. Житейское море. Жизнь с её заботами и волнениями. <Житейски, нареч.

(там же)

Comment: Скорее всего, это задание тестовое, на паронимы.Человек спрашивает:"Слово жизненные в словосочетании жизненные советы употреблено неверно. На что его можно заменить?" А Вы убеждаете его, что верно. Ему нужна помощь в выполнении задания, а что задание некорректно, это другой вопрос. Хотя я считаю, что вполне корректно. Советы именно житейские, а ситуации жизненные.

Answer (score 0):

Часто встречается сочетание "жизненно важные советы" - советы, важные для жизни.

А вообще говоря, выражение "жизненные советы" вполне возможно употребить в определенной ситуации, как бы подводя итог сказанному, с ударением на первом слове: "да, это жИзненные советы".

Также, к примеру, выражение "жизненный смысл" тоже кажется неправильным, но и его можно встретить в тексте: "Таков жИзненный смысл математики: без неё невозможна была бы ни научная техника, ни вся современная система производства и рынка, ни планомерное ведение современной войны".

Answer (score 0):

*Советы на основании жизненного опыта* - если смысл в том, чтобы сориентировать кого-то в типичных ситуациях, которые ещё не встретились в его жизни, или помочь в новой для человека сложной ситуации.

*Жизненно важные советы* в узком, буквальном смысле - это советы специалиста о поведении в нестандартной или опасной ситуации, когда от правильности действий зависит жизнь или здоровье. Но это же выражение может и просто подчёркивать важность даваемых советов и необходимость им следовать.

Answer (score 0):

> Слово *жизненные* в словосочетании *жизненные советы* употреблено
>   неверно.

А кто сказал, что неверно? По-моему, вполне допустимое словосочетание,

Из учебника по русскому языку для 4-го класса:

https://books.google.ru/books?id=sUppAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA84&dq=%E2%80%9C%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%E2%80%9D&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=zJZZVcDUEaLIyAP1h4GwBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9C%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%E2%80%9D&f=false

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это -- из олимпиад по литературе для старших классов:

https://books.google.ru/books?id=2dMHAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA27&dq=%E2%80%9C%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%E2%80%9D&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=2cRZVey2EsTOygPktoCABw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9C%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%E2%80%9D&f=false

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]